# Will removing themes and modules speed up magento

Tags: magento-1.9, module, theme, cms-block, widgets

I am using a purchased theme for my website and it contains about 14 different themes. I have picked out bits and pieces of all the different themes to create my own child themes and now the others are semi-redundant. I still use templates from the other themes every now and then. But my question is will removing the 'old' themes improve how fast magento loads and will it be significant? I have the same question for modules, cms blocks, and widgets - can they simply be disabled? The main theme came loaded with extras that are not needed and I'm wondering weather it is worth scanning through it all and deleting the unnecessary files. What is the best way to remove the modules? Delete from server or is setting active>false sufficient?

Also if someone can give a simple explanation as to why I would very much appreciate being enlightened as a magento noob.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - keeping magento code base clean and minimal is always good. magento has some weird issue loading all the files, looking for them in multiple locations.
so you must **delete** old themes, layouts and modules/extensions. 
also disabled store views, products is good to **delete**, and completed orders and invoices to **archive** to exclude them from workload.

you need to install Aoe_profiler - it will show you every slow files and plugins.